# release management client compatibility with tfs 2018

Tags: windows, tfs, azure-devops, devops, release-management

Can someone please tell  if the Release management (client/server model) rich client is compatible with the TFS 2018

we are using the Release management 2015 rich client and tfs 2015 and planning to upgrade to TFS 2018 , and wanted to check if this is compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [System requirements for Release Management server/client for VS 2015 and TFS 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/archive/release/previous-version/install-release-management/system-requirements?view=vsts), the supported TFSs are:

•   Team Foundation Server 2017

•   Team Foundation Server 2015

•   Team Foundation Server 2013

•   Team Foundation Server 2012

•   Team Foundation Server 2010

So, I recommended that you can use web-based release management feature instead.

Comment: We will definitely upgrade to use the web version of Release management in future. But before upgrading the TFS 2015 to 2018, we need to know whether RM 2015 client/server model is compatible with the TFS 2018 to make sure the existing things will work properly after update.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Since TFS 2018 is not included in the article, I do not recommend you to use RM 2015 with TFS 2018, it may has the potential issues that can block your work. Web version of RM is the better chose.

Answer (score 2):

Release Management Server is deprecated. It has not received updates since TFS 2015, and will not receive updates going forward.

Since TFS 2015 update 2, Release Management features have been integrated into the **Build & Release hub** in Team Foundation Server (TFS) and VSTS. The newer web-based version is the recommended alternative to the server and client version.

In short, Yes, you can still use the Release Management 2015 (server and client version) with TFS 2018, but no new features will be added to the old versions.

More information please see the official documents:

- [Release Management 2015 (server and client version)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/archive/release/overview-rm2015?view=vsts)
- [What is Release Management?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/what-is-release-management?view=vsts)

> **A newer version of Release Management is available**
>
> Release Management features have been integrated into the **Build &
>   Release** hub in Team Foundation Server (TFS) and VSTS. For more
>   information, see [Build and Release in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/overview?view=vsts).
>
> **The newer web-based version is the recommended alternative to the server and client version** described in this topic. If you do not
>   already have Release Management installed, we encourage you to use the
>   web-based version in TFS 2015 Update 2 and above or VSTS instead of
>   the version described here. **If you are already using an earlier
>   server and client version, you should be aware that no new features
>   will be added to these** versions.

Comment: @pramod Is that answered your question? have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: TFS 2018 is not listed in the supported TFS version of System requirements for Release Management server/client for VS 2015. Can you please check here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/archive/release/previous-version/install-release-management/system-requirements?view=vsts)

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Yeah, that means RM 2015 client/server model is not completely compatible with the TFS 2018. However it will still work partly, to verify this you can simply setup a test TFS2018 in VM or other machine, then check it...

Comment: Sure will check.